# I've connected this program to my database, and every time that I try to run it it shows me this error

Tags: java

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and
> 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String
> types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match,
> a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default
> collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE
> CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')

This error shows when I click the edit button or the delete button. Here's my code

This is the code for edit button:

```
private void UpdateBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if (SerialNumber.getText().isEmpty() ||
        ProductName.getText().isEmpty()  ||
        DateAcquired.getText().isEmpty() ||
        Quantity.getText().isEmpty()     ||
        Description.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Missing Information");
    }
    else {
        try {
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Inventorydb",
                                              "User1",
                                              "1220");
            String UpdateQuery = "Update User1.PRODUCTTBL " +
                                    "set ProductName='"+ProductName.getText()+"'"+
                                       ",DateAcquired='"+DateAcquired.getText()+"'"+
                                       ",Quantity='"+Quantity.getText()+"'"+
                                       ",Description='"+Description.getText()+"'"+
                                 " where SerialNumber="+"'"+SerialNumber.getText()+"'";
            Statement Add = Con.createStatement();
            Add.executeUpdate(UpdateQuery);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Updated Successfully");
            SelectProd();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the delete button

```
private void DeleteBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if(SerialNumber.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Enter the SerialNumber to be Deleted");
    }
    else {
        try {
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Inventorydb","User1", "1220");
            String ID = SerialNumber.getText();
            String Query = "Delete from User1.PRODUCTTBL where SERIALNUMBER="+"'"+ID+"'";
            Statement Add = Con.createStatement();
            Add.executeUpdate(Query);
            SelectProd ();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Deleted Successfully");
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the structure of [database] table PRODUCTTBL, i.e. the names of the columns in the table and the data type for each column. Here is a [list](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/crefsqlj31068.html) of data types.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty descriptive. It is pointing to a incompatible comparisons between integer and char.

As you get the same error in edit and delete I doubt the SerialNumber column.
Try executing the query directly on the database query window to confirm this.

Try by casting char to integer.

Comment: I don't do much SQL but his query is quite descriptive ITSELF! ....Not since beep each commandline entry when I was learning it. The table syntax for selecting is also piece out badly, and only the single item brought back should be cast not with a comparison inside it's brackets.and no varchar() only the name of the column as you define it with dotting to its table.